# jQuery - detect if enter is pressed more than X times in X seconds

Tags: jquery

I got an AJAX chat and this is the code to send messages:

```
$('#usermsg').keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").html();
        if((jQuery.trim(clientmsg)).length==0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
             // .............
        });
    }
});
```

I'd like to detect if someone pressed enter more than 3 times in 2 seconds while on `$('#usermsg')`

What would be the shortest and best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var enterCounter = 0;

$('#usermsg').keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) { // the enter key code        

        if (++enterCounter > 3) alert('pressed enter more than 3 times in 2 seconds');
        setTimeout(function(){enterCounter--;}, 2000);

        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").html();
        if((jQuery.trim(clientmsg)).length==0) {            
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
             // .............
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: quite weird... your setTimeout starts every times I press enter.

Comment: Nice even shorter than I thought it would be :D

Comment: @AnneSchwarz it's shorter than I thought when start write the answer :D

Comment: @AnneSchwarz the setTimeout, should run only one time before time ends. Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40932407/1076753

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countTime=0;
$('#usermsg').on('keydown', function(e){
  var key = e.which;
  if(key == 13) {  // the enter key code
    if (countTime==0){
      countTime++;
      setTimeout(function(){countTime=0},2000)
      var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").html();
      if((jQuery.trim(clientmsg)).length==0) {
        return false;
      }
      $.ajax({
        // .............
      });
    } else {
      countTime++;
      if (countTime>=3) countTime=0;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="usermsg"/>
```

Comment: @iXplo can you see the difference now? ;)

Comment: now we can press it only once per 2 seconds, but we have another task

Comment: @iXplo downvote is for weird answer my friend. Do not use it only for spite.

Comment: @AnneSchwarz just try to understand the difference between the codes. In this answer, the setTimeout, is executed only one time every two seconds and not for each "keypress enter".

Comment: you just write wrong answer and can't keep calm and accept the best way to solve the problem

Comment: your code blocks every `ENTER` press after first one for 2 seconds. My code alerts if `ENTER` pressed 3 times in ANY 2 second interval like in task

Comment: OMG... you can add a counter in **else** so you can count it every time you want. @iXplo Just try to be onest.

Comment: show it. anyway it will be more difficult then my solution. so U'd better stop before your first comment

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: Discussions like this do not contribute to the question and are frankly, really unneccesary.